# App convertion from React.js to typescript with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am struggling with converting this piece of code to typescript, as I am a newbie with TS.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Coin.css';

type Coin = {
  name : string;
  price : string;
  symbol: string;
  marketcap: string;
  volume: string;
  image: string;
  priceChange: string;
} 
{  
return (
    <div className='coin-container'>
      <div className='coin-row'>
        <div className='coin'>
          <img src={image} alt='crypto' />
          <h1>{name}</h1>
          <p className='coin-symbol'>{symbol}</p>
        </div>
        <div className='coin-data'>
          <p className='coin-price'>€{price}</p>
          <p className='coin-volume'>€{volume.toLocaleString()}</p>

          {priceChange < 0 ? (
            <p className='coin-percent red'>{priceChange.toFixed(2)}%</p>
          ) : (
            <p className='coin-percent green'>{priceChange.toFixed(2)}%</p>
          )}

          <p className='coin-marketcap'>
            Mkt Cap: ${marketcap.toLocaleString()}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
 };

export default Coin;
```

I know I have to change this piece of code:

```
const Coin = ({
  name,
  price,
  symbol,
  marketcap,
  volume,
  image,
  priceChange
}) => {
  return (
```

because VSCode gives me errors, but I am not sure how to declare it and after pass it to the return function.
I have tried this:

```
type Coin = { name : string; price : string; symbol: string; marketcap: string; volume: string; image: string; priceChange: string; }
```

and it gives me error that `A 'return' statement can only be used within a function body.`

Comment: What have you tried? What have you converted already? What are the errors? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i have tried this: type Coin = {
  name : string;
  price : string;
  symbol: string;
  marketcap: string;
  volume: string;
  image: string;
  priceChange: string;
}

Comment: but it gives me error on the return method. A 'return' statement can only be used within a function body.

Comment: You've only declared an object with no name in line 13. you should declare a const or something. I wrote a standard code below.

Answer (score 0):

You should first declare your types in an interface or a type (it's better to be an interface, because interfaces are straight forward and can be extended when you need to extend a type.
Then declare a const with the type `Functional Component` (here is React.FC) with passing the props type as generic (types inside `<>` are called generic).

Now you can use the inputs without need of declaring types anymore. (make sure your file type is `.tsx`, because `.tsx` files are Typescript files with React JSX support.

```
interface CoinProps {
  name: string;
  price: string;
  symbol: string;
  marketcap: string;
  volume: string;
  image: string;
  priceChange: string;
}

const Coin: React.FC<CoinProps> = ({
  image,marketcap,name,price,priceChange,symbol,volume
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="coin-container">
      <div className="coin-row">
        <div className="coin">
          <img src={image} alt="crypto" />
          <h1>{name}</h1>
          <p className="coin-symbol">{symbol}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="coin-data">
          <p className="coin-price">€{price}</p>
          <p className="coin-volume">€{volume.toLocaleString()}</p>

          {priceChange < 0 ? (
            <p className="coin-percent red">{priceChange.toFixed(2)}%</p>
          ) : (
            <p className="coin-percent green">{priceChange.toFixed(2)}%</p>
          )}

          <p className="coin-marketcap">
            Mkt Cap: ${marketcap.toLocaleString()}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Coin;
```

By the way, the price change should be a number.

Comment: yes I know about the price change, price etc. I would change it later, the image value though should be a string? I am going to pass actuall images in App.tsx

Comment: The images in the components are usually a link or a base64 data which  are treated as string  @NikDanilov.
Could the answer help you?

Comment: yes i guess i will just leave it as a string